# Can a Comparator for a sorted list in a GWT app be parameterized?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm working on a GWT (Google Web Toolkit) project.  I am building a "form" that will have a series of ListBoxes.  Each ListBox corresponds to a different JSONArray that holds JSONObjects.  I want each ListBox to hold a sorted set of the key/value pairs in the JSONObjects.  I am repeating the same code over and over for each ListBox.  My question is can I parameterize this process?

The answer seems to largely be "yes" until I get to the Comparator for each JSONObject.  The Comparator does not take a parameter and I don't know enough about Java to know how to work around this.  Is it possible?

```
private FlowPanel createWebUsersList(JSONArray Info, String listName) {
    FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
    final ListBox listBox = new ListBox();

    panel.add(new HTML("<h3>Limit by " + listName + "</h3>"));

    listBox.setStyleName("LimitBy");
    listBox.setName("limitBy" + listName);
    listBox.setVisibleItemCount(20);
    panel.add(listBox);

    if (Info.size() > 0) {
        SortedSet<JSONObject> sortedList = Collections
                .synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet<JSONObject>(
                        new JSONObjectComparator(listName)));
        for (int i = 0; i < Info.size(); i++) {
            sortedList.add(Info.get(i).isObject());
        }

        while (sortedList.iterator().hasNext()) {
            JSONObject item = sortedList.iterator().next();
            listBox.addItem(
                    item.get("UserName").isString().stringValue(),
                    Integer.toString((int) item.get("ID").isNumber()
                            .doubleValue()));
        }
    } else {
        Misc.displayError(logger,
                "selectEMSEventsBy.addChangeHandler.onChange: empty WebUsers");
    }

    return panel;
}

class JSONObjectComparator implements Comparator<JSONObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
        return o1
                .get("UserName")
                .isString()
                .stringValue()
                .compareToIgnoreCase(
                        o2.get("UserName").isString().stringValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "take a parameter"? The `compare` method takes two parameters, the two objects being compared.

Comment: You can write a constructor for the comparator and save the "parameters" in member variables.  However, you haven't really provided enough information for us to help you. Tell us what is different about each case and what you want to parameterize.

Comment: Note that `.get("UserName").isString().stringValue()` will throw NPE if `UserName` is not a `String`, as `isString()` will return null in that case.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  What I want to do is basically create a "sorted" ListBox.  The ListBox will of course have "items" and and matching "values".  The items and values come from a JSONArray of JSONObjects.  

The trick is that each array of objects has different key/value pairs.  For example the WebUser list from above has the keys: UserName, NetworkName, ID (int) and a few oters.  There is a list of "groups" and that has keys like: GroupName, ID (int) and others.  There are two other arrays of objects as well.

I am hoping to pass into the Comparator the per list key.

Does that help?

Comment: My answer should give you what you need. You'll have to adapt it to accept multiple key fieldnames but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you had in mind. The constructor takes a String argument containing the name of the field to be compared.

```
class JSONObjectComparator implements Comparator<JSONObject> {
    private String fieldToCompare = null;
    public JSONObjectComparator(String fieldToCompare) {
        this.fieldToCompare = fieldToCompare;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
        return o1
                .get(fieldToCompare)
                .isString()
                .stringValue()
                .compareToIgnoreCase(
                        o2.get(fieldToCompare).isString().stringValue());
    }
}
```

Note that you still have NPE problems if the field is not a String (`isString()` will return `null`).  But that's a separate issue you can fix yourself.

Comment: Thank you Jim and all.  I'll get used to java one day :)